# Assign new name to object's key in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

In a Grid, records are fetched from API and displayed. It also has certain input fields, with text and date field. While inputting data for date its getting displayed two times, as seen in the console, the data from JSON is as `est: 10/20/2022`  but I want to display it as `Establish: 10/20/2022`. What modifications could be made in the code? Please refer to code below.

```
      //Here 'allData' is an array of data from JSON 
      const tempData = allData;

      tempData.map((x) => {
        if (data.id === x.id) {
          x.name = data.textVal;
        }

        // Here I'm trying to assign new key 'Establish' to old key 'est'
        if (data.id === x.id) {
          x["est"] = x["Establish"];
          x.Establish = data.dateVal;
        }
      });
```

Please refer to codesandbox link --> https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-aryabhata-95o2sy?file=/src/Table.js

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? It seems to do exactly what you've described. (You don't need the quoted form, though, just `x.est = x.Establish; x.Establish = data.dateVal;` is just fine.)

Comment: Please add a sample of the expected input/ouput

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl

```
if(data.id === x.id) {
   delete Object.assign(x, {['Establish']: x['est'] })['est'];
}
```

Comment: Its showing 'undefined'... can you please check sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

I think your way works but if you want another way so you can create a new property by using:

```
Object.defineProperty(x, "Establish", Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(x, "est"));
```

Comment: After that you may delete the old one if you want!